# Angular 8 415 Unsupported Media Type,Content type 'application/json' not supported +Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

MY problem,
I can upload files with Postman(Spring Boot).Service works, but when I do it with angular, I get an error.(15 Unsupported Media Type,Content type 'application/json' not supported)

*****Spring******

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> saveProfil(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
```

*******Angular *****

```
 const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','multipart/form-data')

     }
    export class ApiService {
    
      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
    
      postFile(path: string, body: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.post(path, body, httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.formatError));
    
      }
      
    }



 onSubmit(event) {

    const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.fileUpload = file;

    const formData:FormData= new FormData();
    formData.append('file',this.fileUpload);

    this.uploadService.saveProfile(formData).subscribe(res => {.....});

   

}



 saveProfile(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.postFile(apiHost + '/Profil', formData);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `headers` you are sending.
use append or the following constructor

```
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'text/plain');
```

or

```
 const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            "Accept": "text/plain",
            'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'
        });
```

then create the post options like this

```
const httpOptions = {headers: headers};
```

Comment: Sure wish there was more context around that 2nd `headers: new HttpHeaders` business.